# how to get the value from the particular tab hidden fields values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tabs that is loaded dynamically. Now i am putting the values in hidden field values.Now i want to get the those values based on each activated tab.But i tried so many ways but it giving undefined.please help me thanks in advance.

```
$('.maintab').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("data-bprid"); // activated tab
    var ref_this = $(".maintab li .active");
    // i want to get the processid and branchid for specific tab 
    var mydiv = ref_this.find( ".response-report .processid" );
    console.log(mydiv.find('.processid').val());
});
```

```html
<ul id="main_tab_list" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified maintab" role="tablist">
   <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#EXN" aria-controls="EXN" data-bprid="1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Extrusion</strong></a></li>
   <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#WAW" aria-controls="WAW" data-bprid="3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Web & Warp</strong></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="dashboard-tab-content">
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="EXN">
      <div class="response-report"></div>
      <input type='hidden' class="processid" name="pros_id" value="1" >
      <input type='hidden' class ="branchid" name="brs_id" value="1" >
   </div>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="WAW">
<div class="response-report"></div>
<input type='hidden' class="processid" name="pros_id" value="2" >
<input type='hidden' class ="branchid" name="brs_id" value="1" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong selector to get target div element. You can use href value of anchor element in selected item. Use returned value as ID selector to target div having input element:

```
 var ref_this = $(".maintab li.active");
 var targetID = ref_this.find('a').attr('href');
 console.log($(targetID).find('.processid').val());
```

Comment: thanks for ur help. if i remove li it is giving value.

Comment: Oh yes. li and active should be chained together as its for single element. check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

div with class `response-report` is not inside `ref_this` block. also input with class `processid` is not child of `response-report`. so `mydiv` in `undefined` always.

i think this will work for you:

```
$('.maintab').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("data-bprid"); // activated tab
    var ref_this = $(".maintab li.active a");
    var div_id = ref_this.attr("aria-controls");
    var processid = $("#" + div_id).find(".processid").val();
    console.log(processid );
});
```